# SQL Server Rounding issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, rounding-error

I have a problem in data accuracy when I store data in variables/columns.

Consider the following example

```
DECLARE @w NUMERIC(38, 15) = 0.458441,
        @a NUMERIC(38, 15) = 10.000000,
        @p NUMERIC(38, 15) = 5.000000

select  (1+0.458441)*(1+    10.000000/100)*(1+  5.000000/100)
```

**Result :** `1.68449935500000000000000000` (correct)

```
SELECT ( 1 + @w ) * ( 1 + @a / 100.0 ) * ( 1 + @p / 100.0 )
```

**Result :** `1.684499` (incorrect)

Can anyone tell what is the reason for approximation when I store values in variable and how it can be fixed?

Comment: "how it can be fixed?" - stop asking for large data types with large precision requirements when you don't want/need them.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Those are just example's my real time data is very big.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First check datatypes:

```
SELECT '0.458441', system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(N'SELECT  0.458441', NULL, 0) 
UNION ALL   
SELECT '10.000000', system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(N'SELECT  10.000000', NULL, 0)  
UNION ALL   
SELECT '5.000000', system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(N'SELECT  5.000000', NULL, 0);

╔═══════════╦══════════════════╗
║   value   ║ system_type_name ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 0.458441  ║ numeric(6,6)     ║
║ 10.000000 ║ numeric(8,6)     ║
║ 5.000000  ║ numeric(7,6)     ║
╚═══════════╩══════════════════╝
```

Query 1:

```
SELECT (1+0.458441)*(1+10.000000/100)*(1+5.000000/100)
-- 1.684499355
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT (1 + @w) * (1 + @a/100.0) * (1 + @p/100.0)
-- 1.684499
```

After adding casting:

```
SELECT (1 + CAST(@w AS NUMERIC(8,6))) * 
       (1 + CAST(@a AS NUMERIC(8,6))/100.0) * 
       (1 + CAST(@p AS NUMERIC(8,6))/100.0)
-- 1.684499355
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/425145?opt.textResults=true)**</kbd>

Why it is the case: [related article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33417022/how-scale-is-defined-when-decimal-and-bigint-are-divided/33417515#33417515)

Comment: nice one ,I don't know about sys.dm_exec_describe dmv.Thanks

Comment: Thanks for you help now am little clear with my problem. In real time any values can come those are just example's. In this case how can I make it to work is there some thing wrong with `numeric(38,15)`

Comment: The point is that it is **not "wrong"** as you describe it. This is how calculating scale/precision works dependent on datatype of expression's parts. Please see mentioned link.

Comment: @lad2025 - sorry for late reply. Was busy with work. Will get back to you as soon as possible

Answer (score 2):

OK, I know it's already answered by lad2025..but..only half of it (to me at least)..its only answer how to fix it not the reason..

Because of my curiosity, I do my own research on this..after read trough [Precision, Scale, and Length](https://msdn.microsoft.com/id-id/library/ms190476.aspx) and try some SQL I found that NUMERIC(p,s) when multiplied will produce new numeric with new precision and scale of:

```
p1 + p2 + 1
s1 + s2
```

The *approximation* problem is the occur when *p1 + p2 + 1* exceeding 38, the maximum precision sql server can have, the precision set to 38 but the scale reduced by 1 as demonstrated below

```
DECLARE 
    @a NUMERIC(20, 5) = 0.12345,
    @b NUMERIC(20, 2) = 0.13,
    @c NUMERIC(10, 5) = 0.12345,
    @d NUMERIC(10, 2) = 0.13

SELECT 0.12345 * 0.13 Result, @a * @b AxB, @c * @d CxD
```

Result:

```
+-----------+----------+-----------+
|  Result   |   AxB    |    CxD    |
+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 0.0160485 | 0.016049 | 0.0160485 |
+-----------+----------+-----------+
```

AxB give *wrong* result their precision originally exceeding 38 and CxD give the right answer with precision of 21, Further check with *sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set*

```
SELECT '@a * @b', system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(
    N'DECLARE @c NUMERIC(20, 5) = 0.12345, @d NUMERIC(20, 2) = 0.13
    SELECT  @c * @d', NULL, 0) 
UNION ALL
SELECT '@c * @d', system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(
    N'DECLARE @c NUMERIC(10, 5) = 0.12345, @d NUMERIC(10, 2) = 0.13
    SELECT  @c * @d', NULL, 0)
```

Result:

```
+-----------+------------------+
| operation | system_type_name |
+-----------+------------------+
| @a * @b   | numeric(38,6)    |
| @c * @d   | numeric(21,7)    |
+-----------+------------------+
```

The table shows scale reduction on @a * @b..
The thing is I don't know if this intentional or a bug..